# Theft insurance in India

Tags: india, insurance, security

Are there any theft insurance options available while travelling in India. I am an Indian as well and I am planning to travel throughout India for a couple of months. I will be carrying my camera, laptop and mobile phone which I do not want to lose. Even if they are stolen, I want to make sure that my losses are minimum.

Comment: Your household contents insurance might already cover you, otherwise surely you just need travel insurance with personal belongings cover?

Comment: Funny, I've never even thought about travel insurance for domestic travel. It makes sense but I don't know whether travel insurance companies are only about international travel, so maybe this is a good question ...

Comment: Mine current travel insurance covers me equally on everything except medical cover when at home or abroad. Past ones I've had have had exclusions for domestic trips of under a certain length (IIRC minimum 2 days), but beyond that have always covered me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure how Indian insurance companies work or what kind of coverages they offer...

But as a licensed Property and Casualty agent in the US, I know that insurance carriers have something called a "Personal Articles Floater" (PAF) that is a type of policy that will give you worldwide, all-risk coverage for your personal property.
* Ex: People use PAFs for insuring high-value, jewelry etc.

Some carriers in the US offer a similar protection of this type as part of a homeowners insurance policy (but it comes with a higher deductible should a claim occur).

Look at your homeowner's policy, if you've got one, and see what would be covered and whether there are any exclusions or limits (i.e jewelry might be covered up to USD$1000, etc). Otherwise, talk to a knowledgeable insurance agent about a PAF.

However, the cost of insurance is something you also need to consider in comparison with the value of the belongings you're insuring.