# How to declare value of checked in luggage?

Tags: luggage, airlines

In case of lost baggage, based on what does the airlines calculate value of lost baggage (and reimburse)?
The replies to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89/4584) suggest buying insurance, but if one doesn't want to do that is there a way one can declare the value of belongings in checked in baggage ?

Comment: In my experience, they tend to have a $/weight policy.

Comment: @Jonas That was also my impression but it turns out that it's [more complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal_Convention) and that my knowledge of all this was [very dated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Convention). Still, the last time I lost luggage for good was around 2000 and I got compensated by weight, IIRC. Incidentally, those treaties are the reason why maximum liability is defined in special drawing rights.

Comment: Since you asked about transfer in Amsterdam in another question, you might be interested in the [EU rules about passenger rights](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm). Note that you might be able to get something even if your baggage is merely delayed and not lost forever. Often it's just a matter of asking for it to the airline (but it's a long time since I last had to deal with this so I am not sure how airlines handle this nowadays).

Comment: @Annoyed: Agreed. Ground personnel seems to have quite some discretion - I negotiated a decent compensation for a ripped-off bag handle in Beijing, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Each airline is different, however, most of them will inform you of this policy on their specific website. (For Example, [Delta's policy](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/after-your-trip/delayed-lost-or-damaged/declaring-baggage-value.html).)

Also, keep in mind that most airlines will state that they are not liable for:

-Cash, camera equipment, fragile items, jewelry, etc...

For example, I have lost luggage with AA before, and I had to wait at least a week to give them a chance to find it, and I then filed a lost luggage declaration form, and spoke to a person in their Customer Service Dept. after my trip. It took some work, but I did get a fair value from them for my lost items (mainly clothing).

Bottom Line: Keep your valuables in your carry on, or on your person. Check each airline's Baggage Liability Rules. ([Example](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/legal.html).)