# How much should I expect to pay to declare goods I'm carrying, during check-in

Tags: luggage, airlines, qantas

I learned that if I'm carrying valuable goods in my checked baggage I should declare it to the airline, but I will have to pay for it.

How much should I expect to pay?

I'm traveling international with Qantas and carrying many electronic devices (video game consoles, tablets, cellphones) inside one of my baggage. It shouldn't be worth more than USD 1500 but this is much more they would pay in case the baggage is lost.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22109/how-to-declare-value-of-checked-in-luggage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qantas](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/conditions-carriage-full/global/en#jump7) 7.4 Restrictions on Checked Baggage disown liability for damage to:

> You must not include in your Checked Baggage:

```
fragile, delicate or perishable items
computers
items with a special value, such as money, jewellery, precious metals, silverware
negotiable papers, share certificates, securities or other valuable documents
cameras
personal electronic equipment including compact discs
commercial goods or business documents, or passports and other travel documents.
```

> If you carry items in contravention of these Conditions of Carriage, we will use all available defences against any claim in respect of any damage, loss or destruction of those items.

So I would be interested in what you learned where about valuable goods, since if you want them insured it may be that you take out the coverage rather than the airline.